# How to append a random number as parameter in URL

Tags: joomla, url-rewriting, joomla3.3

I have a problem with caching in my site and I think it comes from the Template I am using (JSN GRUVE). Caching is still working even after disabling it in my Joomla settings ( Global configuration, System plugin , Modules )

One way I thought I could get around this problem is by rewriting the URL and adding a random number or session id at the end of it, so I would force the page to be loaded and not be displayed from cache.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do not add a random string if it doesn't affect the content: Google won't like it, nor will your users.

I assume you disabled your cache plugins as well as the configuration; at this point it could be a matter of permissions on the /cache folder; or you could have an unsupported cache provider, try "file" in the global configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery i have managed to assign a custom string at the end of each link on the Main Menu of the site.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.menu-mainmenu').find('a').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).attr('href',jQuery(this).attr('href')+'?zId='+Math.random());
  });
});
```